# How come the Google-Chrome installer auto execute in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, installation

When you install google chrome from firefox, instead of donwloading an installer and then executing it, the installer automagically starts without any standard confirmation from firefox, bypassing even the download manager.

How is this possible? What kind of technical wizardry is google pulling to achieve this? Every other *.exe will prompt me before download.

You can test this by going to the [chrome installation page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), click on download button, and then accept the EULA. The installer will start automatically.

Firefox 16.0.2 on Windows xp
[image: chrome auto install]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're doing it via Javascript and Microsoft's .NET [ClickOnce application deployment system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

More info on ClickOnce from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

An example from CodeProject on how you can implement it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38546/Click-Once-Deployment-Technique).